# Win 32 Dll working in Activex but Crashes in C++/c# Test Application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, activex

I have written a C++ dll for which i have to write a C# wrapper. In Activex wrapper the c++ functions are working properly. But in test application and C# wrapper, The code runs once and in the next time I'm getting memory exception like this .

Unhandled exception at 0x0055365a (msvcr80d.dll) in TestApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000001.

The stack trace showing the error at memset line which is showed below.

```
VOID Clear () {

    if (byFeature != NULL) {
            memset (this->byFeature, '\0', VF_MAX_FEATURES_SIZE - 1 ); ==> crash at this line 
        this->iFeatureSize = 0;
    }
    else
        this->iFeatureSize = 0;

    this->iMinutiaeCount = 0;
    this->G = 255;

}
```

I'm trying to clear byFeature before allocating it. It runs at the first cycle properly. Getting crashed at the second time.

Am i doing it right ?

Comment: Are all parameters valid? Is VF_MAX_FEATURES_SIZE still correct and is this->byFeature pointing to the correct structure. Marshaling from c# to c++ can do strange things to memory addresses and break things.

Comment: @CodingBarfield Ya parameters are valid and this->byFeature points to correct strucure. And the code also executes one cycle properly. When i put it in loop it strucks at this line. Is anyone faced any similar issues.

Comment: It looks like on the second run, `this` has an incorrect value. Stick a breakpoint on that line and see what happens.

Comment: Can you simplify the problem by creating a little scratch program in c++ and c# to see if you can recreate the problem in a way that is easier for us to debug. With the current information only someone that had the exact same problem can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is going on.

- What you have is a **bug**.
- What you need is a **debugger**.

Load it into the debugger, put a breakpoint on that line, or just run it through and when the access violation occurs, the debugger will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I'm new to c++, and i tried to debug the above line, it shows the this variable and byFeature are all as <Bad Ptr>. But when it comes for the first time it has some value and next time and all it becomes <Bad Ptr>

Comment: It means that the pointer you used to call the method is invalid. Find the numerical value of the `this` pointer, and find out why it is invalid.

Comment: ya i got it working !! After each cycle the this variable gets Bad Ptr. I have reinitialized it and made it done. Thanks for your guidance.